# webGL thee.js: pointing a camera at an .obj model

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to work out how to direct the camera directly at an obj model. I have deliberately moved the obj model off center, so that when i achieve this aim, it will become centered in the frame. I've tried using `camera.lookAt( object.position );` after `camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );` but unfortunately this just renders a black screen.

```html
<script>

    var container, stats;

    var camera, scene, renderer;

    //var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

    var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;


    init();
    animate();



    function init() {

        container = document.createElement( 'div' );
        document.body.appendChild( container );

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );

        camera.position.z = 300;
        camera.position.x = 100;
        camera.position.y = 500



        // scene

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x444444 );
        scene.add( ambient );

        var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
        directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1 ).normalize();
        scene.add( directionalLight );

        // model

        var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
            if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
                var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
            }
        };

        var onError = function ( xhr ) {
        };


        THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader() );

        var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
        loader.load( 'obj/male02/male02.obj', 'obj/male02/male02_dds.mtl', function ( object ) {

            object.position.y = - 80;
            object.position.x = - 80;
            object.position.z = - 80;
            scene.add( object );

        }, onProgress, onError );

        //

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        //document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

        //

        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

    }

    function onWindowResize() {

        windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    }


    function animate() {

        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        render();

    }

    function render() {

        camera.lookAt( scene.position );

        renderer.render( scene, camera );

    }

</script>
```

Comment: here you are pointing the camera at the *scene* position .. which you never move. in camera.lookAt( scene.position );

it would be much easier to try to help if you had the code running live somewhere, e.g. as a jsfiddle.

Comment: I shall definitely upload to jsfiddle as my experience increases. Thank you very much for your answer- yes i dont need to look at scene, but rather object(camera.lookAt( object.position );); and more importantly within the context of the var loader function between "scene.add( object );" & }, onProgress, onError );